# Мыльный терминал в VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Переустановил `VScode` и сразу появилась подсказка о смене языка на русский. Я нажал - язык поменялся, но потом я передумал и удалил расширение. Когда в следующий зашёл в код терминал был в мыле и на русском

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ничего в настройках не менял, только потом попробовал сменить шрифт, но не помогло. Снова переустанавливал `VScode`, пробовал менять язык на русский снова и обратно.
При увеличения масштаба консоль становится чётче.
Как починить терминал?

Comment: Помог ответ решить данную проблему?

Comment: да помогло, спасибо

Comment: отлично, на здоровье=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поиграйтесь с настройками для `Gpu Acceleration`.

#### В графическом интерфейсе

1. Открыть `Command Palette`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Ввести `Preferences: Open User Settings`
3. В строке поиска настроек ввести `Terminal Integrated Gpu`
4. Поменять на другую. Попробуйте здесь все предложенные

#### Через файл настроек

1. Открыть `Command Palette`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Ввести `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`
3. В открывшемся JSON файле дописать, например (`on`, `canvas`)

   ```json
    "terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "off",
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Нажми правой кнопкой внутри окна терминала и выбери "переключить размер на ширину содержимого"